# How to upgrade from 9.04 to 13.04?

Tags: installation, upgrade

I've seen [these Upgrade Notes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes) which say that the only upgrade path from 9.04 is to 9.10. And the same notes say that the only upgrade path from 9.10 is 10.04, and so on. [It seems](https://askubuntu.com/a/222056/5786) that I would need to **perform at least 5 upgrades in order to turn a 9.04 installation into a 13.04** -- I hope I misunderstood something!

Given that I have a 9.04 installation that I want to move to the newest version, what's my best course of action? There isn't a lot of stuff on the machine right now, and data is backed up.

What happens to the current installation if I simply pop in a 13.04 CD and just install that?

Finally, if it really is better to wipe the machine and start from scratch, how can I best keep track of (or even preserve!) the installed apps, settings, and so on? Everything except user data itself which is backed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply pop the 13.04 it might end up with mismatching libs and many configuration files being not valid to the newer software versions. Doing a

> dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/packages

will provide you the list of installed files wich you can recover in a fresh install. A good idea is to backup your home with the .config folders and /etc/ to achieve this I suggest you a software like [LuckyBackup](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net).